# Why is bccomp comparing equal?

Tags: php, floating-point

I usually test float comparison by comparing the absolute value of the difference of the floats to an arbitrarily small delta:

```
php > echo abs( (0.1+0.1+0.1) - 0.3 ) < 0.0001 ;
1
php > echo abs( 0.3 - (0.1+0.1+0.1) ) < 0.0001 ;
1
```

Today I discovered the PHP function [bccomp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php) which supposedly performs the comparison, however it does require it's arguments to be strings (and returns `0` if the values are in fact equal)!

From the [fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php), and confirmed in my PHP interpretter:

```
echo bccomp('1', '2') . "\n";   // -1
echo bccomp('1.00001', '1', 3); // 0
echo bccomp('1.00001', '1', 5); // 1
```

**However, these comparisons are not returning what I would expect:**

```
php > echo bccomp(  strval(0.1+0.1+0.1), strval(0.3)  ); // Expect 0
0
php > echo bccomp(  strval(0.1+0.1+0.1), strval(0.4)  ); // Expect 1
0
php > echo bccomp(  strval(0.1+0.1+0.1), strval(0.2)  ); // Expect -1
0
```

To be sure, let's ensure that `strval()` is returning what we think it should:

```
php > echo strval(0.1+0.1+0.1);
0.3
php > echo strval(0.3);
0.3
```

**Why in `bccomp()` returning `0` in the problematic examples above?**

Comment: Perhaps the float arithmetic of 0.1+0.1+0.1 is introducing a marginal error in the result meaning that it isn't exactly 0.3.... simply echoing won't necessarily show the discrepancy

Comment: @MarkBaker: That is **exactly** the use case that `bccomp()` is designed to resolve.

Comment: But you need to be working consistently with strings to use bc functions, not simply casting to strings when you need it.... use `bcadd('0.1',bcadd('0.1','0.1'))` rather than `strval(0.1+0.1+0.1)`..... because the error could be created by the `strval()`

Comment: The problem is that `bccomp()` is evaluating **`0.1+0.1+0.1` as being equal to `0.2`**, so the issue is not Floating Point precision, of which I am intricately aware. Furthermore, **PHP does not have First-Class Functions** (i.e. functions cannot be arguments to other functions). Even if it did, in all languages with First Class Functions (i.e. Python) when the "argument" function is called with arguments then the **return value** of the function is passed, not the function itself.

Comment: But bccomp isn't evaluating 0.1+0.1+0.1...... that's done within before strval() is called, and strval works on the result of that floating point math.... so if there's any float precision error in that math, strval is being called with a value that already has the precision error

Comment: Right, that is why I demonstrated at the end of the post that `strval(0.1+0.1+0.1)` evaluates to `0.3`.

Comment: I'm not altogether convinced that it does..... because the precision of the strvalled result will be dependent on the value of the precision php.ini setting

Comment: Try ' printf ("%.17f",strval(0.1+0.1+0.1));  ' . I get  0.29999999999999999 .

Comment: @RickRegan: That is **exactly** the use case that `bccomp()` is designed to resolve.

Comment: As Mark has said, you need to use it differently for it to work as you expect (use bcadd()  -- see his comment).  If you're giving it 0.29999999999999999... and 0.3, then it is correct in reporting 'not equal'.

Comment: Sorry, I said 0.3, but it's strval(0.3).

Comment: And strval(0.3) = 0.29999999999999999..., so they DO work out equal in this case. But I know the problem for the other examples (will post as answer).

Comment: Setting the precision higher (e.g., ini_set('precision', 17);) , as @MarkBaker alludes to, you can see that the two really ARE different (precision defaults to 14 on my system, which explains my prior results): echo strval(0.3); gives 0.29999999999999999, and echo strval(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1); gives 0.30000000000000004.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the scale (3rd parameter to bccomp()), as done in the examples you cite from the manual. I tried it with a scale of 17:

```
php > echo bccomp(  strval(0.1+0.1+0.1), strval(0.3), 17 ); // Expect 0
0
php > echo bccomp(  strval(0.1+0.1+0.1), strval(0.4), 17 ); // Expect -1
-1
php > echo bccomp(  strval(0.1+0.1+0.1), strval(0.2), 17 ); // Expect 1
1
```

That is the correct output (your expectations were wrong -- you had 1 and -1 reversed).

I guess for what you're trying to do you would adjust the scale to match your delta (e.g., 4). But in general I'd be careful using bccomp() with 'stringified' floating-point results.

EDIT: If you set the precision higher, e.g., ini_set('precision', 17);, the result of the first line will change, reflecting that 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 is greater than 0.3; you'll get 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Actually `bccomp()` _requires_ 'stringified' floating-point arguments! Thanks, Rick.

Comment: @dotancohen What I meant by 'stringified floating-point' is a BINARY floating-point number converted to string. So in general use '0.1' and not strval(0.1) (though this does not apply to your usage).

Comment: In general, arithmetic operations are not done on literals but rather variables. I can think of no good reason to have `0.1+0.1` in code, but rather `$foo+$delta`. Thus the code would not be `strval(0.1) but rather `strval($delta)`.q

Comment: @dotancohen My point is that if you want exact decimal values for the bc* functions', start out your calculations with strings (e.g., '0.1'), not strings derived from floating-point values (e.g. strval(0.1)).